# JS: How to change variable in function (IIFE)

Tags: javascript, function, return, constants, iife

How to change the s variable using IIFE.n() because now it doesn't work. After I execute IIFE.n() IIFE.s still returns "string"

I've tried with this but I rather use let/const and don't want to pass this variable to global scope I want to keep it in module.

```
const iife = (() => {
    let s = "string";
    const n = () => {
        s = 1e3;
    };
    return {
        s: s,
        n: n
    };
})()
```

Currently when I do iife.n() it doesn't change the s variable (when I added return before s = 1e3 it returns 1000 but iife.s still returns "string")

Comment: I'm sure it does change `s`, but there's `s` the local variable in the closure and also `s` the property of the returned object. They're two different things.

Comment: const iife = (() => {
let s = "string";
const n = function() {
this.s = 1e3;
};
return {
s: s,
n: n
};
})()

Answer (score 4):

You will need to return the object inside the IIFE.n() function

```
const iife = (() => {
    let s = "string";
    const n = () => {
        s = 1e3;
        return {
                s: s,
                n: n
            };
    };
    return {
        s: s,
        n: n
    };
})()
```

`iife.n().s` returns 1000
`iife.s` returns "string"

Every time you invoke the iffe it creates its own copy of the variable. In your code when you do `iffe.s` it doesn't know about the previous invokation of `iffe.n()`. It will create a new copy of the variable and return that.

Answer (score 3):

It does change `s`, but you don't have any way to get the updated value, so you can't see that it's changing. Try this and you'll see the updated `s`:

```js
const iife = (() => {
    let s = "string";
    const n = () => {
        s = 1e3;
    };
    const gets = () => s;
    return {
        s: s,
        n: n,
        gets: gets
    };
})();

iife.n();
console.log(iife.gets());
```

`iife.s` is not the same as the `s` variable. The variable was just used to initialize the property, but they're not linked permanently.