# Understanding the IIFE Scoping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iife

I came across something similar. Can someone help me understand why is this behavior happening. Is it something to do with scoping for IIFE?

```
const iife = (() => {
    
    let myValue = "Previous";
    const getValue = () => myValue;
    const setValue = (val) => {myValue = val}

return {
    myValue:myValue,
    getValue:getValue,
    setValue:setValue
}

})()

//console outputs
iife //{myValue:"Previous", getValue:f, setValue:f}
iife.setValue("New");
iife.getValue() //"New"
iife // {myValue:"Previous", getValue:f,setValue:f}
```

How is it possible to get the `iife.getValue() = "New"` value even though it is not changed for `myValue` variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509812/js-how-to-change-variable-in-function-iife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setValue` changes the value inside `iife` function. When you return the new object, it creates the copy of the `myValue` variable, so `iife.myValue !== myValue`. You can see it if you modify the code as follows:

```js
const iife = (() => {
    
    let myValue = "Previous";
    const getValue = () => myValue;
    const setValue = (val) => {myValue = val}

    setInterval(() => console.log(myValue), 100)

return {
    myValue:myValue,
    getValue:getValue,
    setValue:setValue
}

})()

//console outputs
iife //{myValue:"Previous", getValue:f, setValue:f}
iife.setValue("New");
iife.getValue() //"New"
iife // {myValue:"Previous", getValue:f,setValue:f}
```

It will print whatever you put in `iife.setValue`.

Comment: Okay Got it! So basically, the iife.myValue is not being changed as there is no way of writing back the myValue data to it. It's just a copy that was retained from the first invocation. But internally myValue has changed by setValue function.

Comment: Yes, that's the case, both are different variables